# Nested queries , subquery SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables:

```
select * from friends;
```

```
 user_id | friend_id |         created_at         
---------+-----------+----------------------------
 user    | user2     | 2017-01-09 21:29:56.31972
 user    | user3     | 2017-01-09 21:29:58.567925
 user    | user4     | 2017-01-09 21:30:01.200806
 user2   | user      | 2017-01-09 21:30:49.498912
 user3   | user      | 2017-01-09 21:30:53.549042
 user4   | user      | 2017-01-09 21:30:56.519135
```

```
    id | user_id | user_from | message 
----+---------+-----------+---------
  1 | user    | user2     | hey
  2 | user    | user3     | de
  3 | user    | user4     | bal
  4 | user    | user3     | ok
  5 | user    | user3     | nice
  6 | user    | user4     | cana
  7 | user    | user2     | doc
```

This SQL statement successfully retrieves the last message to one user. For example. The last message sent by user3 to user

```
select id, user_from, message 
from messages 
WHERE user_id = 'user' 
AND user_from = 'user3' 
ORDER BY id DESC 
limit 1;
```

```
 id | user_from | message 
----+---------+---------
  5 | user3    | nice
```

**I need to retrieve a collection of messages. Each message represents the last message sent by a friend to an user**

**What I need is to combine a query so that I get something like this**

```
id | user_from | message 
----+-----------+---------
  7 | user2     | doc
  5 | user3     | nice
  6 | user4     | cana
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`distinct on` is the easiest solution here.

```
select DISTINCT ON(user_from) id, user_from, message 
from messages WHERE user_id = 'user'
ORDER BY user_from,id DESC;
```

This uses a postresql extension to the SQL standard, there's also a standard way to do this using window functions, but it's more complicated, and a potentially inefficient way using a self-join.

Comment: This did not work: ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: select DISTINCT ON(user_from) id, user_from, message

Comment: I modified the query with the following...select DISTINCT ON(user_from) id, user_from, message 
from messages WHERE user_id = 'user' AND user_from = 'user3' 
ORDER BY user_from, id DESC;
 id | user_from | message 
----+-----------+---------
  5 | user3     | nice

Comment: But still does not achieve what I want. Only retrieves one row

Comment: @user1000622 try removing `AND user_from = 'user3' `

Comment: this works! select DISTINCT ON(user_from) id, user_from, message 
from messages WHERE user_id = 'user'     
ORDER BY user_from, id DESC;
 id | user_from | message 
----+-----------+---------
  7 | user2     | doc
  5 | user3     | nice
  6 | user4     | cana
(3 rows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use join and window function (for your case is `row_number`).

Assuming the first table is `friends` and the second one is `messages`, this solution might work (not tested yet).

```
select id, user_from, message
from (
  select m.*
    , row_number() over(partition by m.user_from order by f.created_at desc) as N
  from friends f, messages m
  where f.user_id = m.user_id and f.friend_id = m.user_from ) x
where N = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Start by normalizing your database, relational databases need this.

Im not sure how familiar you are with db design and sql. But look into using joins, which work better with a normalized db ;)

Read up about normalization here
http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Also look up joins on w3schools or tutorialspoint, youll get what you need